# What is the best way to have multiple threads read a file at the same time?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, pthreads

What is the best way to have multiple threads read a file at the same time ?

For example, if I tell my program to run with 4 threads and the file is 12 characters long, I want each thread to read 3 chars at the same time.

**This is what I have so far :**

*thread function :*

```
void *thread(void *arg) {
    // can't seem to find the right solution to make it work here...
}
```

*main function (thread_count is the number of threads and text_size the size of text) :*

```
// Number of characters each thread should read
uint16_t thread_chars_num = (text_size / thread_count);

pthread_t threads[thread_count];
for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
    if(i == thread_count - 1) { // last thread might have more work
        thread_chars_num += (text_size % thread_count )
    }
    if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, &thread_chars_num) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create failed!\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

I was thinking of giving to the thread function a struct with index to start reading and index to stop reading, but it's really confusing and I can't seem to find the right solution.

Comment: For a file of 12 bytes you would be better off reading its content entirely on a single thread, and then give each thread its portion of file to process in memory.

Comment: Why do you think your idea would not work?

Comment: That was example, actually the file could be very, very long @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Your idea is actually correct (in case of 12 bytes it's trivial, but still). You need to pass a function & argument to `pthread_create`. The function (`start_routine`) will need to cast the argument (`arg`) to the pointer to your struct then, and then do its own work (seek, read, close). Basically, you can provide _the context_ to the thread through that argument.

Comment: That's a good point if you think my idea is correct, I was thinking I was doing things completely wrong. How would I change the common line `while((ch = getc(f)) != EOF) {` to something like `while(index != index_to_stop_reading) get_ch(index)` ?

Comment: In portable C? Open the file several files. In Linux-specific C? Use `pread`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, but I'd just need a quick example so I can continue going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a struct like:

```
struct ft 
{
    char* file_name;
    int start_index;
    int end_index;
};
```

Then in your thread:

```
void *thread(void *arg) {
    int i;
    int c;
    struct ft* fi = (struct ft*)arg;
    FILE* file = fopen(fi->file_name);
    fseek (file , fi->start_index, SEEK_SET);
    for(i = 0; i < fi->end_index - fi->start_index; i++)
    {
        c = getc(file);
        //do something
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to do `pthread_join` in your main thread, which will make it wait for the other threads to finish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! I'll try to make that work with my program and keep you in touch if I have any problem.

Comment: I guess it would be worth to add mention of `pthread_join` in main thread, to wait for all the workers to finish.

Comment: I've got the following error : `encode.c:40:14: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct ft’
     fseek (fi->f , fi->start_index, SEEK_SET);
`.

Comment: You must define the struct before using it, like at the top of the file.

Comment: is `c = getc(fi->f);` right ? It seems to make pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Right, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much, the program is still not printing anything. Can you quickly check the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WqBRTdXZ) to see where the issue is ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't know what load_file does but you might want to use rewind on the file before spawning the threads: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/

Comment: load_file is just fopen and error checking. I tried to add rewind but didn't get any change. Actually whatever I try to print in thread function, it doesn't show up in console, even if it's not linked to file. Maybe I can't print anything from thread ? Or is it because I return NULL ?

Comment: This is going to have a race condition if several threads execute that at the same time with the same `FILE *`, which the linked code on pastebin does.  This is because the file position manipulated by `fseek()` and `getc()` is per-file, not per-thread.  Since you are using POSIX, you are better off using raw file descriptors and the `pread()` function to directly specify an offset to read from in each thread.

Comment: I'll look into that tomorrow. Thanks for help again.

Comment: ***No!*** This will only work if you're lucky or if the file is small. What do you think will happen if one thread calls fseek, then the other thread calls fseek, then the first thread calls getc? It will read the second thread's data!

Comment: Right, changed to open file in thread. Or go with pread as per caf.

Comment: Finally, I used pread to do it, because using fopen multiple times on same file was generating some issues.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Could you please share the final implementation of this? I'm struggling over here and would love to see how you resolved it.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114099/does-fopen-return-null-pointer-if-file-is-already-open/50114472#50114472, this implementation is not portable as we assume multiple seeks are independent, which by standard is not defined.